# Dynamic Primefaces:tabView doesn't update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.4 (also tried 3.3) and Mojarra 2.1.7. But I have a problem updating my dynamical tabs within a p:tabView.

I have 2 buttons which should add an additional tab. The first button is outside the p:tabView. When clicking this button, the backing bean is called, the p:tabView is updated, and the new tab is shown. But when I click the second button, which is inside a tab of that tabView, the backing bean is called, but the tabView is NOT updated.

This lack of updating occures only in dynamic tabs. When I modify the given example to have only one tab, and displaying a value which changes when clicking the buttons, the tabView is updated by both buttons, and the new Value is shown. So it is an problem only occuring in dynamic tabs.

Here is my code.

```
   <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="press me" action="#{idTestBean.addTab}" update=":ApplicationTab"/>
        </h:form>

        <p:tabView id="ApplicationTab" cache="false" dynamic="false"  var="tab" value="#{idTestBean.tabList}">
            <p:tab title="tab" closable="false" >
                <p:panel>
                    <h:form>
                        <p:commandButton value="press me" action="#{idTestBean.addTab}" update=":ApplicationTab"/>
                    </h:form>

                    #{idTestBean.count}
                </p:panel>

            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </f:view>
```

The different tabs contains separate forms that needed to be submitted separate. therefore I had the approach of more than one form.

Comment: why are you using 2 form tags? Try putting everything in one form tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this must do the trick:

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="press me" action="#{idTestBean.addTab}" update="@form"/>


    <p:tabView id="ApplicationTab" cache="false" dynamic="false"  var="tab" value="#{idTestBean.tabList}">
        <p:tab title="tab" closable="false" >
            <p:panel>

                    <p:commandButton value="press me" action="#{idTestBean.addTab}" update="@form"/>


                #{idTestBean.count}
            </p:panel>

        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but inside the different tabs, i have some panels, that needed to be committed independently from other panels. So my approach was to only have form inside the different taps.

Comment: Ok that's not a problem you can still update the different tab objects in one form. But can you post your Tab object and your bean so i can make the answer clearer for you.

Comment: sorry, I have been in holiday, so my answer comes a bit late. You are right, I can handle my different objects in one form. But The Fields of each tab can be more than 500, so I wanted to post only one tab each time. But I have to do some investigation on tis.

Answer (score 0):

Today i did the same problem too, I had a dynamic tabview, and inside tabs, there're some panels that needed to be updated when tab changes, so what i did was, i added the p:ajax on event TabChange, and in the update attribute, i added the form id and tabviewId like this:

```
:formID:tabViewID
```

and it worked at last. 
Just so you know.